# Error with Java APM agent on kubernetes: Failed to handle event of type METRICS with this error: / by zero

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-apm

I am trying to run **Java APM agent on Kubernetes with Springboot 2.3.1.RELEASE**

**I get the following error**

[elastic-apm-server-reporter] ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - *Failed to handle event of type METRICS with this error: / by zero*

It works well if I run it on VM with same Java version

**How I am using**

```
java -javaagent:elastic-apm-agent-1.17.0.jar -Delastic.apm.service_name=myapp -Delastic.apm.application_packages=com.example -Delastic.apm.server_urls=http://apm-server:8200 -jar my-application.jar
```

**APM Agent language and version**: Java, elastic-apm-agent-1.17.0.jar,1.16.0.jar, 1.15.0.jar

**Java version**

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.12.0) (Alpine 8.212.04-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

**More logs**

```
co.elastic.apm.agent.util.JmxUtils - Found JVM-specific OperatingSystemMXBean interface: com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean
co.elastic.apm.agent.configuration.StartupInfo - Starting Elastic APM 1.17.0 as myapp on Java 1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation) Linux 3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64

co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.ElasticApmTracer - Tracer switched to RUNNING state
co.elastic.apm.agent.servlet.ServletVersionInstrumentation - Servlet container info = Apache Tomcat/9.0.36

ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Failed to handle event of type TRANSACTION with this error: / by zero
```

I tried with previous agent versions 1.16.0 & 1.15.0 but I still get the same error.

Can anyone please help me.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my bad, the server urls weren't correctly passed to docker.